# Is there a new length limit for answers on SO (and not SF)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, character-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post)

I have, on SO, some rather lengthy answers:

- [ClearCase wants to merge unchanged files after deliver to alternate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090911/clearcase-wants-to-merge-unchanged-files-after-deliver-to-alternate-target/1092659#1092659)
- [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495)

And they seem to be truncated after about 3400 characters.
If I edit those answers, I do have the full content though, so nothing is actually *lost*.

By contrast, on SF, a similar lengthy answer (a little less than 7000 chars) is displayed in full:
"[How do you install ClearCase 7.1 on a Unix-based server with no GUI and no internet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49786/how-do-you-install-clearcase-7-1-on-a-unix-based-server-with-no-gui-and-no-intern/49787#49787)"

Is this a bug? a feature?
Those answers **used to be displayed correctly (in full) before this week-end**, and they do not contain internal site links as reported in the MSO question "[Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post)".
According to the MSO question "[Please increase the maximum allowed length for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/please-increase-the-maximum-allowed-length-for-answers)", the limit should be 30K (more, *more* than enough. 7000 is my "record", and I hope I will never break it)

Comment: Relatedness:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

Comment: @random: nope: I did mentioned that link in my question. I do not believe this is the same problem. Again: before this w-end, the answers were displayed correctly.

Comment: disagree, I think it is what random cited. Try saving them by adding a space.

Comment: Weird. Adding a space works. I guess I did not revisit those answers since Augut 7, then. And since my lengthy answer on SF has been written August 13th, that would explain why it has not been truncated. Anyway, thanks.