# Uploading code for small projects

Tags: feature-request, source-code

Yeah, I know this great idea has been pooh-poohed by the people that know better.

I think it is a huge mistake personally, but you got the keys to the car, so OK.

Why not allow a user option to filter out questions with uploaded code and have it default to filter?

Did you see Code Project's Browser add-in that allows a user to browse postings from within Visual Studio and open up the project in VS with a single click? Too cool.

A much higher percentage and better quality of of answers would be provided if people could open up the code and tweek it to find the solution.

Does anyone care to point to a competitor site that allows upload? I wanna go there.

Comment: So you are ready to move to a competing web site with possibly less visitors and less quality answers, just to be able to upload some code? That feature must be *really* important to you :)

Comment: I too agree that uploading code would be nice.  It can be viewed or not as the answerer desires.  Alas, those with the "keys" (and many others) do not agree.

Comment: I'm not just ready to move. I'm ready to implement a similar site with this ability.

Comment: @Pecka: Why do you assume that lower quality answers are associated with the ability to upload code? I would argue the quality would go UP! if the "questions" were runnable code that didn;t have to be reproduced with great effort, the reviewer could dig into the problem with great focus instead of generalities. Further, the code answer would be of more value. The only hurdle is to provide a way to significantly the amount of code uploaded and to pro grammatically render it for the lazy freaks

Answer (score 2):

Users aren't restricted from sharing code-samples. In most of my javacript answers, I refer to items I've posted on jsbin.org, and users are typically able to navigate there with ease. I'm not sure an *actual* problem exists.

If you need to share code, perhaps you should consider http://pastebin.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can always share snippets of code that is relevant to the problem; that's what the "format as code" option (with the binary icon) is for.

It's not often that one needs to include more code than is allowed by the rather large length limit. Can you give an example of where this would be useful?

Comment: You mean there is a length limit!?

Comment: @ear: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13748/please-warn-people-instead-of-silently-clipping-answers-over-max-length

Answer (score 0):

The idea of hosting bigger chucks of code than can reasonable be posted inline was rejected because "Help me [do|fix|complete] my project." is not a question in the Stack Overflow sense of the word.

In other words, the fact that you can not do this isn't a problem for Stack Overflow.

If you have a specific problem, show us a limited (preferably minimal) code sample that exhibits the problem. As a bonus you may learn something (or even fix the problem yourself) while preparing the abstracted version of the code.

---

**Added**

> Did you see Code Project's Browser add-in that allows a user to browse postings from within Visual Studio and open up the project in VS with a single click? Too cool.

Gak!

All the world is *not* running Microsoft's platform.

Comment: +1 alternatively, if really really need be, post your code to pastebin.org or one of the dozens of other similar sites.

Comment: Yep, or a link to your repository if is public.

Comment: Gak!

What are you implying? That this feature would only be available for MS sample code? I can live with that.